# Chrome 65 change to download blob automatically in Chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, download, blob

I've got a Google Chrome App (Windows & Mac) written in JavaScript with a menu item to automatically download a log file. I've been successfully using https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js with no problems up until Chrome 65. Now, when the user clicks on the menu item, I get the following console error:

```
Can't open same-window link to "blob:chrome-extension://lcgcc...1904"; try target="_blank"
```

So I tried adding target="_blank" and now when I click on the menu item I get a **dialog**:

```
There is no application set to open the URL blob:chrome-extension://lcgc...6b11.
Search the App Store for an application that can open this document,
or choose an existing application on your computer.
```

Clicking "Cancel" on the dialog makes it go away but of course the file isn't downloaded.

Here is a simple jsfiddle from another question (not mine) which has similar code:
http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/cW7W5/

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "octet/stream"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = { x: 42, s: "hello, world", d: new Date() },
    fileName = "my-download.json";

saveData(data, fileName);
```

I've tried this sample code within my app and it shows the same behavior: an error message without target="_blank" and a dialog with target="_blank".

Note that this code will work fine in the Chrome browser - it automatically downloads the blob file. It's only a problem in Google Chrome apps, and only since I upgraded to Chrome 65.

I **know** that Google Chrome apps are going away "soon" but in the meantime, until I can find someone to rewrite the entire application, I really need a solution for all of my users (short of telling them to not upgrade Chrome...).

Does anyone know of a different way to automatically download a blob file that won't run into these problems on Chrome Apps? It doesn't need to be cross-browser because it's a Chrome App.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into the same problem, here is how I solved it and my notes.

Chrome 65 made a change where anchor download attribute is ignored. This causes anchor click to do a redirect instead of a download. This only happens if clicked URL is cross-origin. Apparently the blob: protocol at start of url makes it cross-origin or something.

So, to get around it, use the chrome-platform-only APIs available to chrome apps and extensions. Turns out they added a new API and did not mention it some time ago called chrome.downloads.

So let's say you have a blob object to start. First, add the "downloads" permission to the app in its manifest. This will enable the "chrome.downloads" api.

Then do the following:

```
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
const args = {url: url};
const callback = function() {};
chrome.downloads.download(args, callback);
URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
```

I can confirm that I just did this in Chrome 66 on Mac and it now shows the save as dialog as desired.

I am very unhappy with this solution because it is not cross-platform, but at least it works.

API Docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

Comment: This looks fantastic. Unfortunately, when I add the "downloads" permission and reload the app I get the following error: "'downloads' is only allowed for extensions, but this is a packaged app." It looks like chromium is aware of the original bug and may be fixing it (fingers crossed!): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=821219

Comment: Looks like the chromium team fixed the original bug in Chromium 66 (see link in comment above).